Bash - redirect command to dialog and var with tee
How can I display the output of a command (including stderr) with dialog programbox in real-time and also capture the piped input in a var?
So far, I could only achieve either one of these goals.
As pointed out here, tee /dev/tty should work, but the ongoing piping and stdout redirection for dialog's output seems to prevent successful capturing in the following example.
Instead, the output will get printed in the terminal (as /dev/tty usually does). What do I need to change, to make it work?
#! /bin/bash
exec 3>&1
output=$(git worktree remove -- "mytestbranch" 2>&1 | tee /dev/tty | dialog --colors --no-collapse --programbox 20 120 1>&3)
exec 3>&-
echo -e "OUTPUT: ${cmdOutput[@]}"

I've seen other approaches with tee, which redirect directly into a command, similar to this:
cmdOutput=$(git worktree remove -- "mytestbranch" 2>&1 | tee >(dialog --colors --no-collapse --programbox 20 120 1>&3) | cat)

That way, I could actually get the output to dialog AND the var, but afterwards, the tty output seems to be messed-up, i. e., keyboard input isn't displayed anymore in the terminal, at least in cygwin - the commands typed are still parsed and their output is displayed, though.
A closer observation reveals, that the script, from which the command is run, seems to return early (without programbox waiting for the OK keypress); the first time pressing ENTER after running it makes the cursor disappear, the second time makes it re-appearing several lines above in the terminal.
When re-selecting the last command from the history in this state instead, the error -bash: OA: command not found is displayed.
What might be the cause and how to prevent the misbehavior?

Why not use the simple output=$(git worktree remove -- "mytestbranch" 2>&1); dialog --colors --no-collapse --programbox 20 120 <<<"$output" ?

The idea here was to preserve the real-time progress displaying inside the dialog, which would be lost by storing the command's result in a var first.

Use process substitutions like so:
var=$({ git ... 2>&1 | tee >(cat >&3) | dialog ... >/dev/tty;} 3>&1)


Would you care to elaborate on why and how this works in detail? As I interpret it, as follows - first part: redirect stderr to stdout, 2nd part: redirect split-off combined stream of stdout + stderr from stdin to fd3, while passing the same on to the last pipe part of dialog, whose output is redirected directly to the terminal. The curly braces repalce the exec commands in my example inside the same subshell (?) What's actually captured in var, is the output of cat. Is that correct?

@fozzybear Yep, that's correct

@fozzybear It can, though. Exit from command substituion with whatever status you want and it'll be the exit status of your variable assignment. x=$(false | true; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]}); echo $?. If there's more ask a separate question instead of posting comments

I didn't know it was possible to also exit from a {...} substitution of the same process the same way, thanks for the hint.
